# I run the script and it freezes me but varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) -1 always the ones with throws. How max turns -1

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_logtable_script]
    (@table_name varchar(max)) 
RETURNS varchar(max) 
AS BEGIN
   declare @sql varchar(5000)
   declare @column_name varchar(max), @data_type varchar(max), @maxlength varchar(5)

   set @sql = 'create table TEST_Log.dbo.log_'+@table_name+' (logid [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,log_time date, log_tip varchar(10)' 

   declare itable cursor LOCAL for 
        SELECT
            COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        ORDER BY
            ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN itable;
FETCH NEXT FROM itable INTO @column_name, @data_type, @maxlength

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set SET @sql = @sql + ','+@column_name+' '+@data_type+case when isnull(@maxlength,'')= '' then '' else '('+ @maxlength + ')' end

    FETCH NEXT FROM itable INTO @column_name, @data_type, @maxlength
END

SET @sql = @sql + ')'   
CLOSE itable
DEALLOCATE itable

RETURN @sql
END
```

Comment: This question is far from clear. Please explain better what it is that you're observing and what you expected.

Comment: Have you anything else as just an SQL script to explain what you need to know? And the title ... well... it doesn't say much to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is `-1` for `MAX` so your output string is `varchar(-1)` which is not correct, use:

```
set @sql = @sql + ','+ quotename(@column_name) + ' ' + @data_type +
           case when @maxlength is null then '' else 
               '('+ case when @maxlength = -1 then 'max' else @maxlength end + ')' 
           end
```

Note the addition of `quotename` to handle reserved/spaced column names.
This approach wont work for types with a scale/precision.

Comment: Thank you

well, if this table exists 'table', say

is that possible ?

Comment: this control where do I do that

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.get_logtable_script
(
    @table_name SYSNAME
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE  
          @object_name SYSNAME  
        , @object_id INT  
        , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)  

    SELECT @object_name = name, @object_id = [object_id]  
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name, 'U')

SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [TEST_Log].[dbo].[log_' + @object_name + '] (
      [logid] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [log_time] [DATE]
    , [log_tip] [VARCHAR](10)
    ' + STUFF((  
    SELECT CHAR(13) + '    , [' + c.name + '] ' +   
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1  
            THEN 'AS ' + OBJECT_DEFINITION(c.[object_id], c.column_id)  
            ELSE   
                CASE WHEN c.system_type_id != c.user_type_id   
                    THEN '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(tp.[schema_id]) + '].[' + tp.name + ']'   
                    ELSE '[' + UPPER(tp.name) + ']'   
                END  +   
                CASE   
                    WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary')  
                        THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1   
                                        THEN 'MAX'   
                                        ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5))   
                                    END + ')'  
                    WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar')  
                        THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1   
                                        THEN 'MAX'   
                                        ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5))   
                                    END + ')'  
                    WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset')   
                        THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'  
                    WHEN tp.name = 'decimal'  
                        THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'  
                    ELSE ''  
                END +  
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL AND c.system_type_id = c.user_type_id   
                    THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name  
                    ELSE ''  
                END +  
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1   
                    THEN ' NULL'  
                    ELSE ' NOT NULL'  
                END
        END  
    FROM sys.columns c WITH(NOLOCK)  
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id  
    LEFT JOIN sys.check_constraints cc WITH(NOLOCK)   
            ON c.[object_id] = cc.parent_object_id   
        AND cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id  
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id  
    ORDER BY c.column_id  
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 5, '') + CHAR(13) + ');'  

    RETURN @SQL

END
```

Test:

```
USE [master]
GO

SELECT dbo.get_logtable_script('dbo.spt_monitor')
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE [TEST_Log].[dbo].[log_spt_monitor] (
      [logid] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [log_time] [DATE]
    , [log_tip] [VARCHAR](10)
    , [lastrun] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
    , [cpu_busy] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [io_busy] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [idle] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [pack_received] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [pack_sent] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [connections] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [pack_errors] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [total_read] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [total_write] [INT] NOT NULL
    , [total_errors] [INT] NOT NULL
);
```

My post:

[How to Generate a CREATE TABLE Script For an Existing Table](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/)